# in a XAF DevExpress project, What if I modify the *.bo.designer.cs classes

Tags: devexpress, xaf

Is a XAF DevExpress project on WindowsForm, we just make the class/BussinesLogic and the framework does the rest(UI, dataAccess).

I am new at the project(XAF DevExpress also) and I see that my teammates modify the *.bo.designer.cs classes, but these classes have the next note:

```
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// <auto-generated>
//     This code was generated by a tool.
//
//     Changes to this file may cause incorrect behavior and will be lost if
//     the code is regenerated.
// </auto-generated>
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

they have been working this way for a while.

Are we doing it wrong?

when is the code regenerated?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yep, you're doing it wrong.. It will be re-generated at some point -- I've found it pretty inconsistent as to when that happens.

Those generated classes are either abstract or partial, so you should be able to just cut and paste your code into a separate file and be good to go. Reference here: https://documentation.devexpress.com/#Xaf/CustomDocument3258

Comment: ok, thank you, its time to change the way to do that. Have you worked with this framework?

Comment: Yes, it is wrong to modify the *.designer.* files, because they are regenerated every time you make changes in the visual designer and save them. Instead, put your custom code changes into the partial class. Copying the code from the *.designer.* files into separate files, removing the original designer files and continuing with the Code-First approach is also fine.